# Mac OSX remove Hide Window keyboard shortcut

Tags: macos, keyboard-shortcuts

When I press <kbd>command</kbd><kbd>H</kbd>, the current window is hidden. I'd like to disable this shortcut, because I'm using it in another application.

I opened `System Preferences -> Hardware -> Keyboard -> Keyboard Shortcuts -> Application Shortcuts -> All Applications`

I tried adding "No Action" as MenuTitle and <kbd>command</kbd><kbd>H</kbd> as KeyboardShortcut
(see screenshot below).

[image: screenshot]

But this doesn't work.

What am I doing wrong?

**Edit**: What solved my problem was assigning shortcut <kbd>command</kbd><kbd>Option</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>H</kbd> to actions like "Hide Eclipse". Since I never press this key combination, this action never gets executed.

Comment: That won't override an existing command. As every app has a different command for Hide, e.g., Hide Safari, Hide TextEdit, etc., you can't do it that way either. You'll need something like Karabiner or BetterTouchTool

Comment: Your Edit answer worked for me. Sure doesn't affect all apps but this is the easiest way forward thanks.

Answer (score 37):

Adding an answer based on the **Edit:** above as it took me a while to figure this out.

If you want to disable the <kbd>⌘</kbd>-<kbd>h</kbd> shortcut you have to do it per-app.

First open the app, and confirm from the preferences what text option the shortcut is mapped to.

Using [Kitty.app](https://github.com/kovidgoyal/kitty) as an example, for me it's `Hide kitty`.

[image: Original Kitty Preferences Screenshot]

Then you open `System Preferences` and go to `Keyboard` -> `Shortcuts` -> `App Shortcuts` and then click `+`.

Limit it to the relevant app, enter `Hide <yourappname>` (e.g. `Hide kitty` in my case), and pick an obscure key combination. I use the section symbol because it's not in my default layout so I won't type it by mistake.

[image: System Preferences Screenshot]

Now when you click on the Application's menu, you should see your new shortcut has been set, and <kbd>⌘</kbd>-<kbd>h</kbd> will no longer hide that application.

[image: Kitty Menu after changing the shortcut]

Unfortunately there doesn't seem to be a way to do this for all apps.

See also this [MacOS User Guide page](https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/create-keyboard-shortcuts-for-apps-mchlp2271/mac).

Comment: This might be obvious, but how are you supposed to actually type the section symbol into the shortcut field? You can't use option+6 because it'll just map the shortcut to that combination.

Comment: @tay It was possible for me to make that combination on my UK layout keyboard, it might not work for you

Comment: @taylorthurlow you can just choose any shortcut you won't accidentally press (e.g. Cmd-Control-Option-Shift-\). It can also be done via the command line.

Comment: Awesome. Ironically, I was trying to disable that precisely for kitty

Comment: this is brilliant.

Comment: I take it the name has to be an exact match.

Comment: You are my hero of the day.

Answer (score 16):

Adding yet another option:

If you use the Karabiner app (extremely useful in its own right), there is a "Complex Modification" that disables command-h window hiding. [Install the app](https://pqrs.org/osx/karabiner/) and see the listing: Prevent unintended command-h hide window on [this page](https://pqrs.org/osx/karabiner/complex_modifications/).

Comment: this removes the combination all-together, meaning you can't use the combination as a hotkey anywhere else

Comment: This is the best option for me. Thank you Luke!

Answer (score 1):

The (very non-ideal, but functional) way that I solved this problem is to use [Alfred](https://www.alfredapp.com/) to define a global hotkey mapping <kbd>Command</kbd><kbd>H</kbd> to nothing. You could use any app capable of defining global hotkeys to do this (ex. BetterTouchTool or KeyboardMaestro).

Here's the Alfred workflow that I used:
[image: My Alfred Workflow, which just registers global hotkeys for CMD-H and CMD-SHIFT-H and does nothing with them]

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use 3rd party applications, try the following sh command:

```sh
app="IntelliJ IDEA" # rename me
bundle=$(lsappinfo info -only bundleID "${app}" | cut -d '"' -f4)
defaults write "${bundle}" NSUserKeyEquivalents -dict-add "Hide ${app}" nil
```

Make sure to rename the app with yours, and restart the app after running it.

Comment: The value `nil` gets interpreted as `N`. Using `''` resets the shortcut to <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>H</kbd>.

Comment: This will only work some of the time on non-English systems, as most programs will display the menu option in the native language and then some apps use English instead. So keep that in mind when writing a more involved shell script to bulk fix things.

Answer (score 0):

### Overriding keyboard shortcuts Via macOS Terminal

In this example, I change the "Open Viewer" menu option in Apple Photos to "Space", like it used to be pre-2017:

---

```
defaults write com.apple.Photos NSUserKeyEquivalents -dict-add "Open Viewer" -string " "
```

Reset to defaults:

```
defaults delete com.apple.Photos NSUserKeyEquivalents
```

Change the global shortcut for "Preferences" to "⌘ + p" (the "-g" option means "Global", and "@\" translates to "⌘"):

```
defaults write -g NSUserKeyEquivalents -dict-add "Preferences" -string "@\\p"
```

---

**A word of warning though:** 
Do *not* paste this into your Terminal window if you don't feel comfortable with altering the default settings of macOS apps, or if you don't fully understand what it means.

Comment: The question asked about Command-h: can you show that here?

Comment: `defaults write -g NSUserKeyEquivalents -dict-add "Hide" -string "@\\m"`I tried that to replace ⌘+H with ⌘+M it did nothing.