# How can I use cmd+H within a VMWare VM?

Tags: linux, keyboard-shortcuts, vmware, vmware-fusion

I'm running a linux VM inside VMware on an OSX host. Most of the cmd+* shortcuts are correctly passed through to the VM (e.g. cmd+q is handled by the VM rather than closing the window).

However, this doesn't seem to work for cmd+H. I'm using [dwm](https://dwm.suckless.org/) on the linux VM, where super+H is used to expand the main window. However, pressing cmd+h just causes the mac speakers to beep. Other shortcuts work (e.g. pressing cmd+L shrinks the main window in the VM). Following https://superuser.com/a/1328252/161008, I remapped a different key combination to "Hide VMware Fusion", and that new key combination shows up in the VMware fusion dropdown, but cmd+H still causes a beep instead of being passed to the VM.

Comment: In order to send system command, hypervisors typically require you to use an alternate key combination, what alternate key have you configured VMWare to use in a case like this?

Comment: Hi @Ramhound, can you clarify what you mean by a "system command"? I don't think super+H is anything "special" to the linux system, just a regular key combination like any other.